# Creating a vs code extension using Rescript

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, rescript

I am new to using rescript and trying to convert an extension I started writing in typescript into rescript. I cannot figure out how to access the vs code extension api though.

Is there a way to create a vs code extension solely using rescript or should I just keep the typescript boiler plate?

Comment: can you convert rescript to JavaScript?

Comment: You need to either find or create some bindings to it. As an example, here are some bindings I started on before BuckleScript and ReasonML became Rescript: https://github.com/glennsl/bs-vscode/blob/master/src/vscode.re